# Eclipse: Jspf can't be open with Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, ide, jsp-fragments

My Editor can't open JSPF Files in Eclipse.

When i go to: "file Associations" & "Content Types" menus, jspf are associated with "JSP Editor " But it does not working.

[image: file associations]

[image: Content Types]

When i try to open a ".jspf file" I have this message:

```
Unsupported content type in editor.
To associate file extension with a supported content type,
please see Content Types Preference Page
```

And log errors

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.507
!MESSAGE StructuredTextEditor being used without StructuredDocument

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.507
!MESSAGE          Input Name: doDBMailMessageAttachements.jspf

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.508
!MESSAGE         Unexpected IDocumentProvider implementation: org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.508
!MESSAGE         Unexpected IDocument implementation: org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.507
!MESSAGE StructuredTextEditor being used without StructuredDocument

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.507
!MESSAGE          Input Name: doDBMailMessageAttachements.jspf

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.508
!MESSAGE         Unexpected IDocumentProvider implementation: org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-08 15:04:45.508
!MESSAGE         Unexpected IDocument implementation: org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocumen
```

EDIT:

I have only one additional plugin which is "Enhanced Class Decompiler".

New logs Errors:

```
!SESSION 2021-11-09 17:14:19.378
----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.21.0.I20210906-0500 java.version=16.0.2 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_FR Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-11-09 17:14:23.971 !MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-11-09 17:14:23.971 !MESSAGE A conflict occurred for COMMAND+SHIFT+T: Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+T,    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,       Open a type in a Java editor,       Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),      org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@2330c995,        ,,true),null),  org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,     org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system) Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+T,   ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,         ,       Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@7d086485,        ,,true),null),  org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,     org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-09 17:14:31.813 !MESSAGE StructuredTextEditor being used without StructuredDocument

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-09 17:14:31.814 !MESSAGE     Input Name: doMailBody.jspf

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-09 17:14:31.814 !MESSAGE     Unexpected IDocumentProvider implementation: org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2021-11-09 17:14:31.815 !MESSAGE     Unexpected IDocument implementation: org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 2 0 2021-11-09 17:14:32.391 !MESSAGE Can't find Navigator Content Descriptor with id: org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.EnhancedJavaRendering

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 2 0 2021-11-09 17:14:32.391 !MESSAGE Can't find Navigator Content Descriptor with id: org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.EnhancedJavaRendering
```

[image: right click]

Comment: Please show your log starting with `!SESSION` (delete the log, reproduce the issue and add the whole log). What does the right-click _Open With_ menu show? Did you installed additional plugins into Eclipse?

Comment: Are there supposed to be differences between the various images? As far as I can tell, they're all the same.

Answer (score 1):

It was because in:
"Content types" => "Custom Content-Type",

a file associations '*.jspf' was created without associated editor.

I deleted this association and it works fine.

[image: custom]